# How to prevent `sbt dist` to ask for [Enter]?

Tags: bash, playframework, sbt

I want to provide an easy copy-paste install manual for my play application.

```
 sbt dist
 cp target/universal/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip  /tmp
 unzip my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
...
```

This works when copied line-by-line, but not when pasted as a whole. The problem appears to be, that the newline behind `sbt dist` causes the current session to switch into the `sbt` console, kindly asking:

`For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode...`

After entering interactive mode (caused by pasted newline), it then fails on the following commands like `cp`, and `unzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing down the question above I found an answer myself [under this thread](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3091).

`sbt -batch dist`

worked for me

`sbt dist < /dev/null`

shows another alternative.